# What is the best solution in this context present simple or continuous?

Tags: continuous

**are you planning** to reissue this record?

**do you plan to** reissue this record?

I think the second one is better because there is not a limitation of time it can be in 2 days or in 2 years. Could we understand that the decision of reissuing the record has already been decided with are you planning

Comment: I think " are you planning" is more appropriate because you are currently planning to do something in the future.

Comment: To my ear both are fine. The first is, as @anouk suggests, more immediate. #1 is like asking "do you currently have any plans to reissue this record?" #2 is like asking "do you think you might ever consider reissuing this record."